# Rewrite pseudocode in C and Python

Tags: python, c, pseudocode

Rewrite the following pseudocode segment using a loop structure in the specified languages:

```
k = (j + 13) / 27
Loop:
If k > 10 then goto out
k = k + 1
i = 3 * k – 1
goto loop
out: ...
```

a. in C

b. in Python

I think in C is like:

```
for(k=(j+13)/27; k<=10; k++; i=3*k-1)
```

but i'm not sure. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: SO is not your code factory and we do not do your homework.

Comment: We can help you fix your code. Try to do it yourself and show us your attempts then the good people of SO will try to help.

Comment: The first step in writing pseudocode is to understand the target language well enough so that the pseudocode has some semblance of the final result.

Comment: @jramirez i think he had tried using for loop?

Comment: Your C code is close - I think one would usually do `for(k=(j+13)/27; k<=10; k++) i=3*k-1;` though. Tell us what you tried in Python and we can help there too. Want to use a `while` loop? It seems closer to what the pseudo code is hinting at...

Comment: As an aside, when it looks like you copied your homework assignment verbatim (just read the opening line of your question...) you will get a large allergic reaction from the community and pick up a ton of downvotes / close votes / negative comments in the first few minutes. If it looks like you thought about wording the question carefully, and trying to solve it yourself, you will get better response. Sometimes people say "I am really stuck on this homework; I don't want a solution, but can you give me a hint?" that will also get a more positive reaction. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Python:

```
k = (j + 13) / 27
while k > 10:
    k += 1
    i = 3 * k - 1
```

Though the assignment statement for i seems pointless each time, and could be placed outside of the loop, and work all the same.

Your above C code will work, but it is a tad on the un-readable side. Cleaner it might look:

```
k = (j + 13) / 27;
while(k <= 10)
{
    k++;
    i = 3 * k - 1;
}
```

If you use that C code is personal opinion, over what you already have made; and the Python code will work none-the-less.

Comment: The condition is incorrect.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The condition should be while (k <= 10)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `for  loop`

```
   for( statement 1 ; condition ; statement s ) 
   {

     // body of for loop 
     // your statements here 

   }
```

**How the flow works**

```
1) statement 1 gets executed only once
2) then checks the condition and if it returns true, control enters into loop
   else exits the loop
3) statement s is executed and jumps back to 2nd step and continues the process
```